# developing android messaging app and estimating bluemix cost for the messaging app

Tags: android, parse-platform, ibm-cloud, cost-management

I was trying to decide what to use for my android messaging app.
Is bluemix/Parse/ good fit for android messaging app? or Please recommend one if it is better.
Moreover, it is hard to estimate the cost of using bluemix service. 
Every time user send message (very short)/receive message as push notification is considered as Light API Calls ?

I used this page https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/pricing/cloudOEPaneId=pricing&paneId=pricingSheet 
but it doesn't look like right estimate.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 4):

Bluemix mobile push is charged per million push notifications per month. The first million push notification per month is free. Each additional million push notification per month is charged $20 USD.

To get an idea of how many pushes you do per month, you may sign up for a completely free trial account that would last 30 days (no need to enter credit card information). After that, if you think the cost is reasonable, you may sign up for a Pay-As-You-Go account (the first million push per month is still free).